# Iterate through array 1000 items at a time in an array of thousands

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to loop through an array consisting of thousands of items. I want to process thousand item at a time. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

let multiplier = 0
let set= 2
for(let i = 0; i< a.length; i+=set) {
  let p = set * multiplier
  let q = (set * multiplier) + set
  multiplier += 1
  
  const eachSet = a.slice(p, q)
 await API.post("/test", eachSet)  
}
```

Comment: Yes, with back-end coding (Node, PHP, etc)

Comment: Can you please provide a little more in depth info on how to achieve that??Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically no: everything on a webpage ultimately has to come from that webpage, so there's no magic way to add `<script>` tags to the HTML ... except to actually add them.

Generally sites solve this by having a single `<script>` tag for their main "package" of Javascript, and then they have that package bring in all the others that the site depends on. There are numerous libraries for doing this sort of "packaging" (Webpack being the current most popular).

However, you still do need that initial script tag even with such bundlers.  Another solution many sites have to this is to have a "single page" site, which uses only one HTML page, and then they use Javascript to simulate "virtual pages" on the site.  React with React Router would be an example of this.

But if you already have a large mess of HTML files, you either need to add that tag manually, or have a computer add it for you.  Assuming you don't want to do it by hand, you really have two options in that case.

The first would be to get a proper webserver, one that can add the script tag to each file, as it serves it.  The second (which I'm guessing will be easier) would be to just write a simple command line script to append a string (of that script tag) to the end of every file.

I'm not sure how familiar you are with Node.js (ie. Javascript outside the browser), but you could pretty easily whip something like that up using Node's `fs` (filesystem) module.

Comment: I have already done that using Node. But, i am not sure if i can achieve 100% accuracy with this method. As a single error can mess up the whole thing. Thanks for your reply

Comment: HTML validators are usually designed to be easily run against large messes of HTML, so you could use such a validator after running your script as one possible  "safety net". But ultimately, you're right: when you make automated changes, there's always a risk something will go wrong.  One other thought: if you want to "manually review" what your script does, and you're using a source control tool like Git (you should), you can run `git diff` after running the tool, to review all changes without having to go into each file and look.